# Show an alert when image changes on website

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a GitHub pages site with an image on it. I am trying to have the webpage show an alert whenever I push a change to the website.

My approach so far has been to implement an auto-refresh function:

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 60000);
```

This will auto-update every minute, catching all of the changes that I make. However, I need to show an alert whenever the content of the page changes. It is important to keep in mind that the content will not change upon every refresh -- maybe only every 10 minutes (when I push changes).

I think the way to do this would be to store the name of the image and then look to see if the image name changes at every refresh -- and if the name did change, then show the alert. I have been reading about something called LocalStorage, but I'm not sure how to approach storing the name of a file -- I'm sort of new to JS/HTML.

Is using LocalStorage the best approach to this problem? What are other alternatives/simple ways to implement this on a GitHub page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I clearly understand what you need to implement, I'd suggest you to read about **MutationObserver** in JavaScript. This class tracks all the changes, that are made to binded element. Here's the code and working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2aL6czge/):

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
Some content
</p>
</body>

<script>
// select the target node
var element = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  alert("Some changes were made");
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true}; // ,subtree: true, characterData: true 

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(element, config);

setInterval(function () { // here you can make your changes programatically
element.innerHTML += "New content";
}, 2000)
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use cookies, i.e. store in a cookie the last "version" of whatever - where "version" can be a string, a number etc.

This has the advantage that it also gets sent to the server, so you may generate the alert layout/code directly on the server.

Check https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie for a script simplifying this.

Another alternative is to implement on the server a script that responds whether the content changed. Something like `http://foo.bar/changed?lastVer=XXXX` which can return a JSON like `{changed:true,message:'We have changed the change'}`. You would retrieve this via ie. `jQuery.getJSON()` or vanilla `XMLHttpRequest`, and if it's the case show the message to the user and then reload the page. But this would require making a runnable server script somewhere.

A third option would be to load the page into, say, a hidden IFRAME, check if the image or content changed and if so transplant only the image - or a certain piece of content - to the main page without refreshing it. Or maybe refresh it. The idea is to load the page in an IFRAME and detect there if something has changed.